# Bulk data need to insert/update using Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I need to insert/update 500 records using Entity Framework in C#. In that 500 records new as well existing records there. In this scenarios how can I do?

If exception is happening that record should be skipped, other records need to updated.. Please help me with this... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is not the right choice in this case, even considering the bulk insert instruction. When you launch a SaveChanges() command even a single error will undo the transaction because EF will always try to prevent inserting any wrong data (also, is not capable of separating important errors from non important errors).

Possible choices:

1. Insert and save each rows within a try/catch block (it works, but it's very slow and painful)
2. Go for SqlConnection and a plain old MERGE instruction between a temporary table with your data and the destination table (definitively better) - check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb510625(v=sql.120).aspx).